# How to use multivalue parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, multivalue

I have 1 table.  1 have 1 multi-value parameter listing all properties called PROPERTIES.  I want the table to display 1 property per row at a time.

The table has roughly 20 columns, referencing different datasets throughout.

All of the datasets that reference the property have a: `WHERE RMPROPID IN (@PROPERTIES)` and the dataset has `@PROPERTIES` value of: `=JOIN(Parameters!PROPERTIES.Value,",")` (This creates the list of properties selected)

The table has a single row, referencing the different datasets.  The tables dataset is `SelectedProperties` and the group by on the row is `=Fields!RMPROPID.Value`

The `SelectedProperties` dataset looks like this:

```
SELECT
   RMPROPID,
   propname
FROM
   RMPROP
WHERE
   RMPROPID IN (@PROPERTIES)
```

Whenever I choose more than one property it does not work.  Nothing is returned.  Is there a trick I am missing?  I want 1 row to reference one property at a time.

Comment: Is SelectedProperties populated through a Stored Procedure or a query embedded in the report?

Comment: Query embedded in the report.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your redefintion of the parameter as you pass it to the query:

You shouldn't have this part:
`=JOIN(Parameters!PROPERTIES.Value,",")` This **doesn't** create a list of the selected values. It creates a **single** value that is a string combining all of the selected values.

Replace the bit above with just `=Parameters!PROPERTIES.Value`. SSRS will take care or putting the multiple values into the SQL query appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, when I do this, it does display all the selected properties, appropriately, but when I do it for the datasets that the table columns call, it shows the same information for all properties listed.  It should be only running that property through the datasets at a time, but it's either running just the first property or both combined.

Comment: @user What is the expression(s) in the "table columns"? This sounds like another issue. You should be using a lookup function or trying to combine your datasets into one query. Can you update your question, please?

Comment: I don't believe Lookup is in SSRS 2005, I could be wrong though.  A few of my datasets are similar to this...'SELECT (SELECT WHATEVER FROM XX WHERE RMPROP IN @PROPERTIES), (SELECT WHATEVER FROM XX WHERE RMPROP IN @PROPERTIES)'  and then individual table columns call the individual columns from select, like this: '=Sum(Fields!units.Value, "TotalUnits")'

Comment: @Jamie - can you tell me when we have to use JOIN vs when not to use?

Comment: @variable `JOIN` takes a array of separate values and puts them together in one string. But SSRS multi-value parameters are meant to take an array of values. Occasionally a stored procedure is written to take a single, comma separated string as a hack to accept multiple values. If you have that, use `JOIN` but otherwise don't use it.

Comment: @JamieF - I am a bit confused. My SSRS report has got a multivalue parameter and I directly pass that into the dataset parameter which is a stored procedure - without a JOIN function - it gets passed as comma separated string into the SP. Then in the SP I split this parameter value into a table.

Comment: @variable It's been years since I've worked on this, but if I recall correctly, the difference will show more when you are handing parameters in to a SQL statement, of which a SP could be part. But if you have it specified as a direct call to an SP in SSRS designer, than I think the results will be the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the index at the end like so:

Parameters!< ParameterName>.Value(0)

You could do an index based on your row return or something similar to that.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Where would this statement be stored precisely?  Where is "the end"?

Comment: (0) is the end.  You are specifying an index inside the () after the Parameters!< ParameterName>.Value.  To get a single value from a single parameter named @String I would do this: Parameters!String.Value if it were an array I would do this Parameters!String.Value(0) to get the first one Parameters!String.Value(1) to get the second, etc.

Comment: If you are on row 1 you need a pointer or something similar.  You should be able to do something like: Parameters!String.Value(Fields!ID.Value).  I have never done this but I am guessing if you have a valid int and put it inside a method wanting an int index it would validate.  I still don't even get what you are trying to accomplish.  It seems like you are just packaging up properties in an array and then wanting to call them one at a time.... but in a certain way.  But based on what?  What is your criteria for basis.  Just a table showing one thing a time or a comma separated string?

Comment: The table only has 1 row, and it is supposed to repeat for every value selected from the multivalue parameter.  The row has datasets inside each column that reference the multivalue parameter also.  I just want each row to represent 1 propertys data.

Comment: Okay now I am really confused, you said the table has 1 row and you want each row to represent 1 property's data.  If your goal is that you have a working array list and want to iterate based on your statement, you could do this expression: Parameters!Properties.Value(Fields!RMPROPID.Value).  If you are looking for more I would need examples of what your parameter currently contains and the dataset.

Comment: Well, the 1 row seems to be iterating correctly based on my multivalue parameter now!  However, the datasets are still not working with the "WHERE rmpropid in (@PROPERTIES)...The datasets are called in the row by different columns. Does this make sense?

Comment: You need to validate that your parameter is getting properly created it seems.  It should 'Display' on the top unless you have it turned to hidden or internal.  If you are not getting a correct multivalue it will not iterate correcltly, or if it only has a single value it won't show more.

Comment: I dont think you're really following the issue I'm having, but thanks anyway buddy.

Answer (score 0):

A non-performant but working way is to use varchar(MAX) and get the UIDs in comma-separated fashion.
Then you can do a LIKE on it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tfu_RPT_SEL_Gebaeude]
( 
     --@in_mandant varchar(3) 
    --,@in_sprache varchar(2) 
    --,@in_groups varchar(8000) 
    --,@in_stichtag varchar(50) 
     @Standortkategorie varchar(MAX) 
    ,@Standort varchar(MAX) 
) 
    RETURNS table 
AS 
RETURN 
( 
    SELECT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001' AS RPT_FID_SK_UID, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS RPT_FID_SO_UID, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS RPT_UID, 'Ohne' AS RPT_Name, 999999999 AS RPT_Sort 

    UNION 

    SELECT DISTINCT 
         ISNULL(T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_SK_UID, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AS RPT_FID_SK_UID 
        ,T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_SO_UID AS RPT_FID_SO_UID 
        ,T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_UID AS RPT_UID 
        --,T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_MDT_ID AS RPT_MDT_ID 
        --,ISNULL(GB_Nr, '') + ' - ' + ISNULL(GB_Bezeichnung, '') AS RPT_Name 
        ,T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_Bezeichnung AS RPT_Name 

        --,T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_Bezeichnung AS RPT_Sort 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_Bezeichnung ASC) AS RPT_Sort 
    FROM T_AP_Gebaeude 

    WHERE (1=1) 
    -- AND (T_AP_Standort.SO_MDT_ID = @in_mandant) 
    AND (T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_Status = 1) 
    AND (T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_DatumBis >= CONVERT(char(8), { fn NOW() }, 112)) 
    AND (T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_DatumVon <= { fn NOW() }) 

    --AND ( ISNULL(T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_SK_UID, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') IN (@Standortkategorie) ) 
    AND ',' + @Standortkategorie + ',' LIKE '%,' + ISNULL(CAST(T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_SK_UID AS varchar(36)), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') + ',%'

    -- AND ( ISNULL(T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_SO_UID, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') IN (@Standort) ) 
    AND ',' + @Standort + ',' LIKE '%,' + ISNULL(CAST(T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_SO_UID AS varchar(36)), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') + ',%'


    /*
    AND 
    ( 
        ( @in_groups = '0000') 
        OR 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                ISNULL(SUM(CAST(SOR_IsRead AS int)), 0) AS SOR_IsRead 
            FROM T_SYS_Standortrechte 
            WHERE (1=1) 
            AND T_SYS_Standortrechte.SOR_SO_UID = T_AP_Standort.SO_UID 
            --AND SOR_SO_UID = '274751EB-AED4-4E4C-B6D1-57C4FDBC8925' 

            AND @in_groups LIKE '%,' + CAST(T_SYS_Standortrechte.SOR_GRANTEE_ID AS varchar(36)) + ',%' 
        ) > 0 
    ) 

    AND 
    ( 
        ( @in_groups = '0000') 
        OR 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                ISNULL(SUM(CAST(GBR_IsRead AS int)), 0) AS GBR_IsRead 
            FROM T_SYS_Gebaeuderechte 
            WHERE (1=1) 
            AND T_SYS_Gebaeuderechte.GBR_GB_UID = T_AP_Gebaeude.GB_UID 
            --AND GBR_GB_UID = '274751EB-AED4-4E4C-B6D1-57C4FDBC8925' 

            AND @in_groups LIKE '%,' + CAST(T_SYS_Gebaeuderechte.GBR_GRANTEE_ID AS varchar(36)) + ',%' 
        ) > 0 
    ) 
    */

)


GO
```